# "src/common.hpp:52:32: fatal error: boost/shared_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory" when building websocket++

Tags: c++, build, makefile, ubuntu-12.10, websocket++

I know next to nothing about linux or c++.

I generally followed these instructions to build boost on ubuntu 12.10 http://piyushparkash.blogspot.com/2012/10/installing-boost-150-in-ubuntu-1210.html.  I downloaded 1.53.0.

I followed the advice of at the end of 1.2.2 and did `./bootstrap.sh --exec-prefix=/usr/local` because I wanted all libraries.

I get this error `src/common.hpp:52:32: fatal error: boost/shared_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory` when I `make` outlined here https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/wiki/Build-Library.

When I `find / -name 'shared_ptr.hpp'`, it lists

> /root/boost_1_53_0/boost/asio/detail/shared_ptr.hpp
>   /root/boost_1_53_0/boost/interprocess/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp
>   /root/boost_1_53_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp
>   /root/boost_1_53_0/boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp
>   /root/boost_1_53_0/boost/shared_ptr.hpp

Shouldn't they have been installed to the default and specified directories as explained in the first link?

How can I resolve this error?

(I did this to get "all" libs https://askubuntu.com/questions/259590/libapache2-mod-fastcgi-not-available)

**`apt-cache libboost-all-dev`**

1.49

**`apt-cache search boost | grep dev`**

```
libboost-date-time-dev - set of date-time libraries based on generic programming concepts (default version)
libboost-date-time1.49-dev - set of date-time libraries based on generic programming concepts
libboost-dev - Boost C++ Libraries development files (default version)
libboost-iostreams-dev - Boost.Iostreams Library development files (default version)
libboost-iostreams1.49-dev - Boost.Iostreams Library development files
libboost-program-options-dev - program options library for C++ (default version)
libboost-program-options1.49-dev - program options library for C++
libboost-python-dev - Boost.Python Library development files (default version)
libboost-python1.49-dev - Boost.Python Library development files
libboost-regex-dev - regular expression library for C++ (default version)
libboost-regex1.49-dev - regular expression library for C++
libboost-serialization-dev - serialization library for C++ (default version)
libboost-serialization1.49-dev - serialization library for C++
libboost-test-dev - components for writing and executing test suites (default version)
libboost-test1.49-dev - components for writing and executing test suites
libboost1.49-dev - Boost C++ Libraries development files
libasio-dev - cross-platform C++ library for network programming
libboost-all-dev - Boost C++ Libraries development files (ALL) (default version)
libboost-chrono-dev - C++ representation of time duration, time point, and clocks (default version)
libboost-chrono1.49-dev - C++ representation of time duration, time point, and clocks
libboost-chrono1.50-dev - C++ representation of time duration, time point, and clocks
libboost-date-time1.50-dev - set of date-time libraries based on generic programming concepts
libboost-exception1.50-dev - set of date-time libraries based on generic programming concepts
libboost-filesystem-dev - filesystem operations (portable paths, iteration over directories, etc) in C++ (default version)
libboost-filesystem1.49-dev - filesystem operations (portable paths, iteration over directories, etc) in C++
libboost-filesystem1.50-dev - filesystem operations (portable paths, iteration over directories, etc) in C++
libboost-graph-dev - generic graph components and algorithms in C++ (default version)
libboost-graph-parallel-dev - generic graph components and algorithms in C++ (default version)
libboost-graph-parallel1.49-dev - generic graph components and algorithms in C++
libboost-graph-parallel1.50-dev - generic graph components and algorithms in C++
libboost-graph1.49-dev - generic graph components and algorithms in C++
libboost-graph1.50-dev - generic graph components and algorithms in C++
libboost-iostreams1.50-dev - Boost.Iostreams Library development files
libboost-locale-dev - C++ facilities for localization (default version)
libboost-locale1.49-dev - C++ facilities for localization
libboost-locale1.50-dev - C++ facilities for localization
libboost-math-dev - Boost.Math Library development files (default version)
libboost-math1.49-dev - Boost.Math Library development files
libboost-math1.50-dev - Boost.Math Library development files
libboost-mpi-dev - C++ interface to the Message Passing Interface (MPI) (default version)
libboost-mpi-python-dev - C++ interface to the Message Passing Interface (MPI), Python Bindings (default version)
libboost-mpi-python1.49-dev - C++ interface to the Message Passing Interface (MPI), Python Bindings
libboost-mpi-python1.50-dev - C++ interface to the Message Passing Interface (MPI), Python Bindings
libboost-mpi1.49-dev - C++ interface to the Message Passing Interface (MPI)
libboost-mpi1.50-dev - C++ interface to the Message Passing Interface (MPI)
libboost-program-options1.50-dev - program options library for C++
libboost-python1.50-dev - Boost.Python Library development files
libboost-random-dev - Boost Random Number Library (default version)
libboost-random1.49-dev - Boost Random Number Library
libboost-random1.50-dev - Boost Random Number Library
libboost-regex1.50-dev - regular expression library for C++
libboost-serialization1.50-dev - serialization library for C++
libboost-signals-dev - managed signals and slots library for C++ (default version)
libboost-signals1.49-dev - managed signals and slots library for C++
libboost-signals1.50-dev - managed signals and slots library for C++
libboost-system-dev - Operating system (e.g. diagnostics support) library (default version)
libboost-system1.49-dev - Operating system (e.g. diagnostics support) library
libboost-system1.50-dev - Operating system (e.g. diagnostics support) library
libboost-test1.50-dev - components for writing and executing test suites
libboost-thread-dev - portable C++ multi-threading (default version)
libboost-thread1.49-dev - portable C++ multi-threading
libboost-thread1.50-dev - portable C++ multi-threading
libboost-timer-dev - C++ wall clock and CPU process timers (default version)
libboost-timer1.49-dev - C++ wall clock and CPU process timers
libboost-timer1.50-dev - C++ wall clock and CPU process timers
libboost-wave-dev - C99/C++ preprocessor library (default version)
libboost-wave1.49-dev - C99/C++ preprocessor library
libboost-wave1.50-dev - C99/C++ preprocessor library
libboost1.49-all-dev - Boost C++ Libraries development files (ALL)
libboost1.50-all-dev - Boost C++ Libraries development files (ALL)
libboost1.50-dev - Boost C++ Libraries development files
libjson-spirit-dev - C++ JSON Parser/Generator implemented with Boost Spirit
libmapnik-dev - C++/Python toolkit for developing GIS applications (dummy)
libmapnik2-2.0 - C++/Python toolkit for developing GIS applications (libraries)
libmapnik2-dev - C++/Python toolkit for developing GIS applications (devel)
libpion-common-dev - lightweight HTTP interface library - common development files
libpion-net-dev - lightweight HTTP interface library - development files
libroot-tmva-dev - Toolkit for multivariate data analysis - development files
libtorch3-dev - State of the art machine learning library - development files
mapnik-doc - C++/Python toolkit for developing GIS applications (doc)
mapnik-utils - C++/Python toolkit for developing GIS applications (utilities)
python-mapnik2 - C++/Python toolkit for developing GIS applications (Python)
```

Comment: Looks to me like all you did was configure boost, with `bootstrap.sh`, did you actually build it with `b2` and then install it with `sudo ./b2 install`? Also, don't build as `root`, do everything as a normal unprivileged user then just install as `root` using `sudo`. People who say "I know next to nothing about linux" and do everything as `root` very quickly make a mess of their system

Comment: @JonathanWakely You caught me.  I just realized I didn't follow *all* of the steps.  This is just a dev server right now.  I've reinstalled the distro many, many times lol.  Why install as root with `sudo` while logged as a regular user?

Comment: Because you're less likely to break your system if you only use `root` to do things that _must_ be done as `root`. Compiling code doesn't need to be done as `root`, so don't do it. Building bits of software you downloaded off the internet as `root` is just dumb, even for "trusted" stuff like Boost, because it forms a bad habit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest making sure the custom place you installed boost is in the include path of the build system.

For the WebSocket++ 0.2.x build system you can set the BOOST_PREFIX (ie /usr/local/) or exact paths to the include and lib dirs if you havent installed them system wide BOOST_LIB_PATH / BOOST_INCLUDE_PATH environment variables to specify custom paths. For 0.3.x there is no library to build, just make sure you use -I/path/to/your/boost and -L/path/to/your/boost/lib/dir or add those paths to your global path. If you use an IDE they usually have ways to add custom include/library paths.

Answer (score 4):

Why build Boost yourself?  Just do `sudo apt-get install boost-devel` and you're done.  And it will put the headers in `/usr/include/boost` so everything will "just work."

Comment: Thank-you for looking!  Is that the latest version?  The creator suggested this method to fully utilize his/her goodies http://askubuntu.com/a/264700/128334

Comment: Run `apt-cache show boost-devel` and you can tell us what version your system offers.

Comment: Anyway, whatever version it is, try it and see if it works.  Ubuntu 12.10 is very recent, so the Boost it offers won't be ancient.

Comment: Sorry, apparently they call it `boost-all-dev` or something.  It doesn't matter, just do `apt-cache search boost | grep dev` and find it.

Comment: Then I'd try installing `libboost-all-dev`.

Comment: Doesn't matter.  One is a synonym for the other I bet.

Comment: A reason you would want to use your own compiled copy of boost: libboost-all-dev in Ubuntu 12.10 is version 1.48/49, dated nov 2011/feb 2012. The version scheduled for 13.04 is the same. There have been four major releases since then adding 10 new libraries and numerous c++11 related updates and improvements. It is certainly not ancient, as in many other distributions, but particularly due to the recent release of c++11, a lot has changed in the last 1-2 years and being stuck with 1.49 until 13.10+ is a bit annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the same on CentOS:

```
yum install boost-devel
```